# Implementing a pause in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, delay

Here you have a simple WPF program:

```
<!-- Updater.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="Update.Updater"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="50"></Button>
            <Label Content="{Binding Label1Text}" Height="50"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Label2Text}" Height="50"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// Updater.xaml.cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace Update
{
    public partial class Updater : Window
    {
        public Updater()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1Text = "It is coming...";
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Label2Text = "It is here!";
        }

        public string Label1Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CategoryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CategoryProperty, value); }
        }

        static readonly DependencyProperty CategoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label1Text", typeof(string), typeof(Updater));

        public string Label2Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(Label2TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Label2TextProperty, value); }
        }

        static readonly DependencyProperty Label2TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label2Text", typeof(string), typeof(Updater));
    }
}
```

The intention is that when you click the button, the first label displays `It is coming...`. Then the program sleeps for 3 seconds, and finally the second label displays `It is here!`. However, the naïve implementation below doesn't work. If you run it and click the button the following happens: The program sleeps for 3 seconds, and then the two label texts are displayed simultaneously. Do you know how to correct the program so that it does as intended?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Button_Click` is invoked by the UI thread, and you **should not** do anything requiring more than a few miliseconds in it, let alone sleeping for 3 seconds. Messages are not processed during that time, your interface is unresponsive, and your application is considered "hung" by the system.

So, that long processing task should be handled by another thread.

Something like that (untested):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Label1Text = "It is coming...";

    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s,e) => { Thread.Sleep(3000); }
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) => { Label2Text = "It is here!"; }
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Links:

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

[Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
label1.Content = "waiting...";

label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate()
   {

        label1.UpdateLayout();
    }));

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
label1.Content = "done!";
```

Comment: Is there any difference between this suggestion and simply calling `label1.UpdateLayout();` without using the dispatcher?

Comment: Yes there is, it won't work by just calling the UpdateLayout. The method returns immediately and schedules the update for later in the UI thread (probably when the Button Click event finishes). Then the thread sleeps for 3 seconds, and schedules another change, and when the Button Click method finishes, the UI thread finally renders the view.

In Windows Forms you can use just the Update method on the Label, but WPF works differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a storyboard and keyframe animation to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

There's a good example in here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationusingkeyframes.aspx

```
<Button Name="myAnimatedButton" Margin="200"
  FontSize="16pt" FontFamily="Verdana">Some Text
  <Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
            Storyboard.TargetName="myAnimatedButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Content)"
            Duration="0:0:8" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">

            <!-- All the key frames below are DiscreteStringKeyFrames. Discrete key frames create 
            sudden "jumps" between values (no interpolation). Only discrete key frames can be used 
            for String key frame animations. -->
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="A" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="An" KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Ani" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Anim" KeyTime="0:0:2.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Anima" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animat" KeyTime="0:0:3.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animate" KeyTime="0:0:4" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated" KeyTime="0:0:4.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated " KeyTime="0:0:5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated T" KeyTime="0:0:5.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Te" KeyTime="0:0:6" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Tex" KeyTime="0:0:6.5" />
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Text" KeyTime="0:0:7" />
          </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>              
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger> 
  </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```